# Sample with Xamarin.Forms and Vuforia?

Tags: xamarin.forms, vuforia

Where can I find a working example that uses the library "Vuforia" in Xamarin.Forms portable (Droid+iOS) for WinPhone I know that does not work?
Or working converted library for specific platform?

Comment: It's a while you were asking this question, do you find any relevant examples / tutorial ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand. Xamarin is for Custom Touches and UI. So when it comes to Vuforia, the only feature it is going to use is the augmentation.

Hence, if you want to use Xamarin for it's functionalities, you can do so but it will not interfere with the Vuforia virtual touch buttons.

I hope this is what you asked for. Examples this specific aren't available online, I would think.